# C# add array to object

Tags: c#, object

I'm trying to create a simple object that will accept as properties a string and an array.

This is how I've tried to get this done:

```
public void addToObject()
{
    List<Vars> variable = new List<Vars>();
    variable.Add(new Vars { Id = "var1", Name = { "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4" } });
}

public class Vars
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

But it returns:

> Cannot initialize type 'ExcelSDRAddIn.UserControlSDR.Vars' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Name is string and you are assigning collection of string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to add a list to a string. What you want is a `List of strings`, which you should declare in your `Vars` class.

```
public void addToObject()
{    
    List<Vars> variable = new List<Vars>();
    variable.Add(new Vars { Id = "var1", Names = new List<string>(){ "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4" } });
}

public class Vars
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Run the code [here](http://rextester.com/QHC6078).

Comment: This will not even compile ('Name' and 'Names')

Comment: @J.Tuc Yes, typo. It will now.

Comment: I finally got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The error is indeed a bit mis-leading. However it refers to your `Name`-property which is declared as a `string`. But you initialize it using a *collection-initializer*.

Also, the names of properties to be initialized need to be matching exactly what's declared in the class.There was a casing issue.

You probably want this instead:

```
public void addToObject()
{
    List<Vars> variable = new List<Vars>();
    variable.Add(new Vars { id = "var1", name = { "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4" } });
}

public class Vars
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<string> name { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: Using the collection-initializer assumes that you initialized the collections *instance* somewhere before adding objects to the collection. So in your `Vars`-class you need a constructor that sets `name` apropriately:

```
public class Vars
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<string> name { get; set; }
    public Vars() { this.name = new List<string>(); }
}
```

Having said this you can even make your `name`-setter private so no-one from outside the class can set the lists reference but only add objects to the list.

Omitting the constructor leads to a NullReferenceException. This is because the collection-initializer is internally changed to something like this:

```
var v = new Vars();
v.id = "var1";
v.name.Add("n1");
v.name.Add("n2");
v.name.Add("n3");
v.name.Add("n4");
```

which surely assumes that `name` is initialized in any way.

Comment: This won't compile since the names in your `Vars` class don't correspond to the names in your `new Vars` object declaration.

Comment: I added the code here http://rextester.com/IEQP33447 and it returns `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` ... any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In class Vars you want name as a list, while the type is string. This can not help you.

```
public void addToObject()
{
   List<Vars> variable = new List<Vars>();
   variable.Add(new Vars { id = "var1", name = new List<string> { "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4" } });
}

public class Vars
{
   public string id { get; set; }
   public List<string> name { get; set; }
}
```

Please use my snippet, this will solve your problem.

Comment: This returns the following error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Vars> variable = new List<Vars>();
            variable.Add(new Vars { id = "var1", name = new string[]{ "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4" } });
            Console.WriteLine(variable);
            Console.Read();
        } 
        public class Vars
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string[] name { get; set; }
        }

copy this snippet.

Comment: make the type of string an array, like public string[] name{get;set;} and when you are adding it to your master list, make a small changes, variable.Add(new Vars { id = "var1", name = new string[]{ "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4" } });
this will work. :)

Comment: @Jurjen technique is also write, if you can not change your name type to array, you can use list too.

Answer (score 0):

Name is a string, you cannot assign a collection to it. This needs to be changed to a list of strings.

Because you are using properties to build your object you will need to provide a new instance of the List of strings to avoid null reference exception that happens when you try what has been originally proposed in other answers.

```
public void addToObject()
        {
            List<Vars> variable = new List<Vars>();
            variable.Add(new Vars { Id = "var1", Names = new List<string>() { "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4" } });
        }

    public class Vars
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<string> Names { get; set; }
    }
```

You can avoid having to initialize Names every time you add a new object to the variable list by creating an instance of Names in the constructor of Vars

```
public void addToObject()
        {
            List<Vars> variable = new List<Vars>();
            variable.Add(new Vars { Id = "var1", Names = { "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4" } });
        }

    public class Vars
    {
        public Vars()
        {
            this.Names = new List<string>();
        }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<string> Names { get; set; }
    }
```